# How to authenticate user based on cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies, jwt, apollo

I've configured my Apollo client & server to work with cookies:

Client:

```
  const httpLink = createHttpLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:9090/graphql',
    credentials: 'include',
  });

  const cache = new InMemoryCache();

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    link: httpLink,
    cache,
  });
```

Server:

```
  const app = express();
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    resolvers,
    typeDefs,
    context: async ({req, res}) => ({
      req,
      res,
      prisma,
    }),
  });
  await server.start();

  const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
    credentials: true,
  };

  app.use(cors(corsOptions));
  app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  }));
  server.applyMiddleware({
    app, cors: corsOptions,
  });

  app.listen({port: 9090}, () =>
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:9090${server.graphqlPath}`),
  );
```

login resolver:

```
  loginUser: async (_, args, {req, res}) => {
    const theUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {email: String(args.email)},
    });
    if (!theUser) throw new Error('Unable to Login');
    const isMatch = bcrypt.compareSync(args.password, theUser.password);
    if (!isMatch) throw new Error('Unable to Login');

    const token = jwt.sign(theUser, 'supersecret');

    res.cookie('id', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
    });

    return true;
  },
```

When I log in on my React app a cookie is set by the server as expected, but I'm unsure on how to use that client cookie to authenticate my user in the server and how to persist the logged in status. The cookie is also added to the request.

It's an http only cookie, so I can't use the cookies information in the client. So I'm thinking I need a function that queries the login mutation each time the app is loaded, and then on the server I can check the request, if it has a JWT token in the request cookies I can authenticate the user.

But I was hoping to get some feedback on this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your login resolver, the cookie should be included in the req's cookie array (You might consider a more unique cookie id than "id", and you should pull the secret from an env file). You could add this middleware to your server to check for and verify the cookie with each request:

```
app.use((req, use, next) => {
    const { id } = req.cookies;
    if (id) {
        const { user } = jwt.verify(
            id,
            process.env.SUPERSECRET
        );
        // put the user onto the req for future requests to access
        req.user = user;
    }
    next();    
});
```

Instead of putting the whole user on the cookie, you could just include the user's id, then add another piece of middleware to query the user's data using that id on each request.